# Publish Tridion Multi Media Component with Tridion ID

Tags: components, tridion, publishing

Is there a way we could define in Tridion to publish binary file using its own TCM ID as file name?

Comment: http://www.urbancherry.net/blogengine/post/2010/02/09/Unique-binary-filenames-for-SDL-Tridion-Multimedia-Components.aspx

Comment: Sounds like a good use case for some type of "minimization" approach. You'll probably want to change the format at least a little. A multimedia component's Tridion Content Manager Identifier (tcm-id) includes a colon (e.g. `tcm:5-123`). The first number is the publication and the last is a unique identifier. Consider url-friendly escaping, or parsing out the parts you don't need.

Answer (score 7):

Starting with Modular Templates' introduction in Tridion 5.3, the default is to publish binaries *without* a unique identifier (which solved a whole bunch of other issues at the time, like knowing the file name before publishing it, pretty useful when your CSS is produced outside the house, for instance).

I am pretty sure there is still one of the AddBinary overloads (see [here](http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/03/which-addbinary-not-to-use.html)) that will publish a filename appending _tcm-12-35 to the file name, just like in the PublishBinary days, but unfortunately cannot test it now.

If your binary publishing is handled by the default finish actions, you will have to modify the file name *after* this TBB executes, as documented by Chris [here](http://www.urbancherry.net/blogengine/post/2010/02/09/Unique-binary-filenames-for-SDL-Tridion-Multimedia-Components.aspx).